# Change JavaScript filter to filter if the value includes/contains a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Currently, this filters out to a specific category name. I want it to filter if it's contained in the string.

In other words, if It selected 'storm' I want the filter to return 'rainstorm'.
(Currently, it will only return 'rainstorm' if the category it's filtering is 'rainstorm')

```
 function showCategory(category) {
        this.title = category;
        let filteredProducts = this.products.filter(product => {
            return product.category == category;
        });
        drawProducts(filteredProducts);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `includes()` method to see if a string contains another string. However, `includes` is case sensitive, witch means that 'storm' and 'Storm' are 2 different things.

If you want to avoid this, you can do something like this:

```
let filteredProducts = this.products.filter(product => {
    return product.category.toLowerCase().includes(category.toLowerCase());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try to filter using indexOf method like this example

```js
const categories = ["cats","dogs","cars","doors"]


function showCategory(category) {
        this.title = category;
        let filteredProducts = categories.filter(product => {
            return product.indexOf(category) !== -1;
        });
        return filteredProducts
    }
    
    
    
console.log(showCategory("ca"))
```